# $(pkg_build_dir) value in OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

What does `$(build_dir)`, `$(pkg_build_dir)` has in OpenWrt. 
I have create the sample helloworld component and created the Makefile by following steps in openwrt.org.

When I try:

```
make package/helloworld/install -j1 V=s
```

it throws below error:

```
Warning: Your configuration is out of Sync, Please run make memuconfig, oldconfi or defconfig!
Entering Directory '.../openwrt'
***no rule to make target 'pckage/helloworld/install'. Stop
Leaving Directory .../openwrt
/home../toplevel.mk:216: recipe for target 'package/helloworld/install' failed.
```

Can someone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

`$(build_dir)`, `$(pkg_build_dir)` are variable defaults used by OpenWRT.
`$(build_dir)`, is the directory that OpenWRT builds to and
 `$(pkg_build_dir)` is a package build directory.

`$(build_dir)` does not need to be defined in the makefile
`$(pkg_build_dir)` can be defined in the makefile as:

```
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
```

With regards to your issue I would also try including the source directory in the makefile:

```
SOURCE_DIR:=/home/johndoe/helloworld
```

and updating the package feeds

```
cd /home/buildbot/source
./scripts/feeds update mypackages
./scripts/feeds install -a -p mypackag
```